# wifi problem with relocated hard drive on ubuntu 13.04

Tags: installation, wireless, 13.04, drivers, hard-drive

I was having trouble installing ubuntu on my desktop seemingly because of the graphics card in it. so instead i installed in onto a HDD on my laptop and everything seemed to be working ok. now when i swapped the disk back into my desktop i cannot seem to get wifi to work. i have tried following some tutorials to no avail. one thing i am trying is going to the additional software section of software & updates and when i see what looks like a wifi card i click to use a driver instead of not to use at all and it always just puts the check mark back onto do not use. any ideas as to what might have happened and how to fix it? thanks!

Comment: It is safe to run it was written by me and some good friends it will help diagnose your wireless issue.
Paste this command in a terminal  `wget -N -t 5 -T 10 http://dl.dropbox.com/u/57264241/wireless_script && chmod +x wireless_script && ./wireless_script` 
It will download a script and create a file named (wireless-info.txt, or wireless-info.txt.tar.gz) in your home folder paste the file here http://pastebin.com/ then paste the link back here.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/uNN1eqmF

Answer (score 0):

With an internet connection please do:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree
sudo modprobe -r wl
sudo modprobe b43
```